# Check the existence of new line in a file before add using SED command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, duplicates

I have one small doubt regarding sed command. For example, I have a file like below.

iptable.save

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

So next time before adding same line to file , here need a check that whether the new line which we are going to enter is present or not in the file.  If present, don't do anything, else enter the new line to the file.  Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use `grep` for this purpose:

```
if [ $(grep -cx "$line" iptables.save) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$line" >> iptables.save  # Append to the file
fi
```

`-xc` means that we want to count the number of lines that are exactly the same as `$line`.

But if you really prefer to use `sed`:

```
if [ $(sed -n '/^'"$line"'$/p' iptables.save | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$line" >> iptables.save  # Append to the file
fi
```

Comment: Hi julienc, am also trying to edit your answer , what you just did.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back tics, use parentheses like this: `if [ $(grep -cx "$line" iptables.save) -eq 0 ]; then`

Comment: `-cx` does not count the number of line that are exactly the same as `$line`, it counts the number of lines which match the regular expression contained in `$line` - a big difference if/when `$line` contains RE metacharacters. Ditto for the sed approach, neither are matching strings they are matching REs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is a job for awk:

```
awk -v line="$line" '$0==line{f=1} END{if (!f) print line}' file >> file
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also help. Example, checking the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, if it does not end in an empty line, add one, if it does end with an empty line, do nothing

```
if [[ $(tail -n 1 /etc/ssh/sshd_config) != "" ]]; then echo "" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config; fi
```